# Producing a list of donors who have setup a recurring donation

Tags: recurring-contributions, reports

I need to be able to pull a list (in CSV or Excel format) that lists people with a recurring donation. This is so we can contact them annually and ask if it's OK to roll over their donation.

I know I can go to an individual contact and see this, but I need to be able to see everyone, not one at a time, so I need to design a report and know what field stores this info, since none of what I see listed seems to relate to recurrence.

Thanks,
Dave
United Way of Monroe County (IN)

Comment: Rather than exporting the contacts you may want to consider using the scheduled reminder functionality in CiviCRM. This can be used to send this sort of reminder automatically. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Search Kit](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/searchkit/what-is-searchkit/) and do a search like this:

[image]

You can add the Frequency Unit field within the "Contact Recurring Contributions" join to filter on month or year depending on what type of recurring you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Andy -- I was able to turn on the extension, and use it to do what I needed.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Advanced Search](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/#advanced-search) to search for recurring contributions:

[image]